# Docker Run yields different result than docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose file with an image that runs an npm install.

```
services:
  test:
    image: company.com/myImage:1.0.2
    environment:
      - HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.com:8080
      - HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.com:8080
```

Running `docker-compose -f ./docker/docker.build.yaml up` fails during the install with some type of dns issue

> npm verb stack FetchError: request to https://company.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm-remote/lodash.merge failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN company.com

however,

Running `docker run company.com/myImage:1.0.2` works

> npm http fetch GET 200 https://company.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm-remote/lodash.merge/-/lodash.merge-4.6.2.tgz 95ms

My company uses a proxy to connect to the internet so my local environment variables contain some proxy env vars.  I tried hardcoding those env vars into the docker compose file but the result stayed the same.
What am I missing?

edit: added env vars I tested with to compose file

Comment: *my local environment variables contain some proxy env vars. I tried hardcoding those env vars into the docker compose file but the result stayed the same.* Show us the variables you presumably have set in the shell and show us the entire docker compose file

Comment: Also, please read [the relevant docker cli documentation on proxy configuration (`docs.docker.com`)](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/).

Comment: I ended up taking out the proxy env vars in my shell and the behavior did not change, leading me to believe those values weren't affecting this issue.

Comment: Why are you re-running `npm install` every time you run a container?  Can you `RUN npm ci` in your Dockerfile, so you don't have to repeat this step over and over?

Comment: npm is not the point of this issue.  The issue is that docker-compose has some type of different network context than docker cli

Answer (score 0):

docker cli by default uses the docker `host` network whereas docker-compose was creating it's own `docker_default` network.  My solution lied in specifying the docker network in the compose file

```
services:
  test:
    image: whatever
    network_mode: "host"
```